# Joomla! 2.5 Menus

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-template

I've just had my website migrated from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5, however, I am struggling with the menus. This might be because of my choice of template.

The website is using the bizglobal 1.7 template. The problem is the top menu: I can set up various menus and submenus, but I want all the menu items to be available. For example, if I select the first top level item then all the ones below are immediately available. But the remaining top level items don't show their children unless I click on the parent menu item - whereupon the original children don't drop down. Pictures are better than words, so please have a look at http://www.simsig.co.uk with the green top menu (currently SimSig and Forum).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module manager look for the module that's displaying your main menu, it should be type menu.

Is the show sub items marked to yes?

Comment: Doh! I knew it would be simple! Thank you.